# Create a button to send information to my mail (blogspot)

Tags: html, blogger

I have this form that if the user fills out the form on my blog page, it will be sent to my email

```
<div class=\'sora-cart-checkout\'>
    <div class=\"post-custom-title\">
        <div class=\"custom-title\">
            <h2>Billing Details<\/h2>
        <\/div>
    <\/div>
    <div class=\'sora-cart-checkout-wrap\'>
        <p class=\'sora-checkout-details\'>Please Enter your Personal Details</p> 
        <div id=\'contact\' class=\'form\'> 
            <form name=\'contact-form\'> 
                <input class=\"contact-form-name\" id=\"ContactForm1_contact-form-name\" name=\"name\" placeholder=\"Name\" size=\"30\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" \/>
                <input class=\"contact-form-email\" id=\"ContactForm1_contact-form-email\" name=\"email\" placeholder=\"Email\" size=\"30\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" \/>
                <textarea class=\"contact-form-email-message\" cols=\"25\" id=\"ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message\" name=\"email-message\" placeholder=\"Phone, Address, Additional Information\" rows=\"5\"><\/textarea>
                <div class=\'sora-checkout-wrap\'> 
                    <div class=\'simpleCart_items\'/>
                    <div style=\"clear: both;\"\/>
                    <div class=\"cart-bot-element\">
                        <div class=\"sora-cart-amount\">
                            <span class=\"sora-cart-subtotal\">SUBTOTAL :<\/span>
                            <span class=\'simpleCart_total\'/>
                        <\/div>
                        <a class=\'simpleCart_checkout\'href=\'javascript:;\'><input class=\'sora-checkout-bill\' id=\'ContactForm1_contact-form-submit\' type=\'button\' value=\'Proceed To Payment\'></a>
                    </div>
               </div>
               <p></p>  
            </form> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="powr-payment-form" id="388c8716_1587333855"></div> 
<style>div#sidebar-wrapper,.static_page .item-post h1.post-title { display: none!important; }.item #main-wrapper, .statc_page #main-wrapper { width:100%;float:none;max-width: 100%; }</style>
```

Comment: Please format your code block, it's unlikely that anyone will take the time to help if you can't post a readable piece of your code.

Comment: where's your question?

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is go to mailchip you can create your landing page there and make a form and a subscribe button and attched the link to your button using

[Find Out More](https://us8.admin.mailchimp.com/landing-pages/preview-published?id=7305)